# What does EV3 stand for?

Tags: mindstorms, terminology, ev3

I am wondering what the official reason behind the name of LEGO's latest MINDSTORMS robotics platform is. What does "EV3" stand for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the official [EV3 FAQ](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/support/faq):

> #### What does EV3 stand for?
>
> This is the third generation of the LEGO MINDSTORMS platform and the
>   "EV" stands for evolution, hence EV3.

The first two generations referred to here are LEGO MINDSTORMS RCX and NXT, respectively.

Comment: ...and presumably the number 3 comes from the fact it's the successor to [NXT 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_NXT_2.0)?

Comment: @Ambo100 No, I don't think so. EV3 is *not* NXT, it's a completely different line. See [this post on the Mindboards forums](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/mindboards/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1623&start=10#p15702) and all following posts for more info

Comment: @Ambo100 I'm not sure the numbers are incremental in that way - NXT started back at "1" effectively after versions 1, 1.5 and 2.0 of Mindstorms Robotics Invention System, so the 3 really comes from the fact that it's the 3rd generation (RIS, NXT and now EV3).